# The proof of Cauchy's theorem for abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

[image]

I am working on the proofof Cauchy's theorem for abelian groups. I have understood the proof completely but I cannot understant the proof which I marked with red.

If group $G$ has a single element them $G$ is trivial group i.e. $G=\{e\}$.  Why the theorem is vacuously true for this case?

If I'm not mistaken the vacuous truth states that elements of empty have the desired property. But I do not see empty set in my problem.

Comment: The set of prime numbers $p$ which divide $1$ is empty.

Comment: As an aside, there is a nicer proof of Cauchy's theorem for general finite groups using a group action. It is more concise and insightful than proving it using the Sylow Theorems. It actually resembles the necklace counting argument for Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: As Qudit has mentioned in another comment, a vacuously true statement also refers to a conditional statement with a false antecedent. In this case, for this fixed $p$, it is not true that $p\mid o(G)$. Thus any consequent following this claim, will be a (vacuously) true conditional statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement of the theorem is for a prime $p$ that divides the order of the group.  For the trivial group, there are no primes that divide its order since the smallest prime is $2$ and the order of the trivial group is $1$.  Thus, the theorem is vacuously true in that case.

Comment: But in the statement of theorem $p$ is fixed. Maybe I am misunderstanding the problem

Comment: @RFZ It makes no difference if $p$ is fixed.  Anyway, the theorem holds for all $p$ that divide the order of the group.

Comment: In vacuous truth we guess that the element of empty set have desired property. In our example, the set of primes is empty so they have desired property. Could you clarify my reasoning?

Comment: How it follows that it for trivial group?

Comment: @RFZ Another way you could state it is that "A implies B" is true if A is false. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: Let $S$ be the set of prime divisors of $|G|$, where $G$ is the trivial group. So $S = \emptyset$. Now let $p \in S$. Do any such $p$ exist? Clearly not. Hence, the theorem holds vacuously for the trivial group.